# How can I do a conditional create with respect to concurrency?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I recently solved an issue in my program that was causing duplicate collection entries. The gist of it: our codebase had a "CreateDocument" method that checks for an object's existence, and if nothing isreturned, creates a new document. (CV is a Mongoose Model)

```
 CV.findOne(searchObj).exec().then(function (found)
                {
                    if (found)
                    {
                       //~do processing~
                    }
                    //did not find the value, so create
                    else
                    {
                        var newCV = new CV({
                            foo: "foo",
                            bar: "bar"
                        });
                        newCV.save();
                    }
```

The first time this code ran, an event was erroneously being called twice, and as a result, all of our results were duplicated. Subsequent runs (even before the double-called event was fixed) did not create additional documents.

Near as I can figure, this duplication happened because both findOne() calls occurred before the first save() call succeeded.

In general, how can I do this kind of conditional creation without worrying about running into concurency issues?

Comment: One way of doing this would be using an [`upsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter). [Unique indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) may also be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you'll need to potentially restructure your code a bit, I'd suggest you use `findByIdAndUpdate` ([reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)), or `findOneAndUpdate` ([reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)). Using the `upsert` option should help:

```
upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false
```

This way, you won't end up with duplicates, and the modification/update will happen atomically on the database server. That may mean that you'll need to specify additional criteria to verify that the document wasn't modified unexpectedly, but that depends on your schema.